# Class Not Found Exception for GuardedString

Tags: java, security, active-directory, azure-active-directory, ldap

Main Class :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        try {
            String password = "Test";
            System.out.println(password.toString());
            char[] passwordToChar = password.toCharArray();

            GuardedString guardString = new GuardedString(passwordToChar);
            System.out.println(guardString.toString());

        } catch (Exception exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.identityconnectors.common.security.impl.EncryptorFactoryImpl
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.EncryptorFactory.getInstance(EncryptorFactory.java:45)
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString.getEncryptor(GuardedString.java:250)
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString.encryptBytes(GuardedString.java:265)
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString.encryptChars(GuardedString.java:242)
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString.<init>(GuardedString.java:91)
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.GuardedString.<init>(GuardedString.java:78)
    at com.ad.createuser.TestCreateUser.main(TestCreateUser.java:31)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.identityconnectors.common.security.impl.EncryptorFactoryImpl
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at org.identityconnectors.common.security.EncryptorFactory.getInstance(EncryptorFactory.java:39)
    ... 6 more
```

Dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.tirasa.connid</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector-framework</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

I'm trying to use "GuardedString" to encrypt password for this I'm writing test code, issue is "GuardedString" is not execuiting properly, I tried to find the issue but nothing worked, might be  I'm doing someting wrong not sure, Let me know the solution,it's important.

Comment: There's no point in calling `String.toString()`

Answer (score 1):

As per comment above, using this dependency works

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.tirasa.connid</groupId>
        <artifactId>connector-framework-internal</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: This solved it for me. My question is, what's the difference between connector-framework and connector-framework-internal? I'll Google, but I'd appreciate any insight, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think that there is nothing wrong with your code. I would suggest reloading maven dependencies for your project.

Comment: I tried but not work, I have also tested this on WebApp, same error there also

Comment: @KomalPrasad I would try downgrading the version then

Comment: It worked, changed the dependecy
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.tirasa.connid/connector-framework-internal -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.tirasa.connid</groupId>
    <artifactId>connector-framework-internal</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.2</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Convert your comment into an answer and accept it so that your question can be closed. Thanks!